# How can I add a HTML5 property to an Ember view

Tags: html, ember.js

Consider I have the following HTML snippet:

```
<div class="content" data-section-content></div>
```

and I want to replace it with an Ember view like this:

```
App.ContentView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName :"div",
   classNames : ["content"],
   ... ( how can i add the >> data-section-content << to the view )
});
```

What is the best way to add the *data-section-content* to the view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it seems to be that 
`<div class="content" data-section-content></div>` is the same 
as `<div class="content" data-section-content=""></div>`

so i can solve the problem by implementing:

```
App.ContentView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName :"div",
   classNames : ["content"],
   attributeBindings : ["data-section-content"],
   "data-section-content": ""
});
```

or shorter

```
App.ContentView = Ember.View.extend({
   tagName :"div data-section-content",
   classNames : ["content"]
});
```